# Getting no response from $scope in angularjs

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

This is my method for getting a single user. The console.log prints the right object, but in when i try to access the `$scope.user` in the `HTML` I get no response, the tags are empty:

```
$scope.getByUsername = function (id) {
    return $http.get('/api/User/' + id).success(function (data) {
        $scope.user = data;
        console.log($scope.user);
    });
}
```

HTML:

```
<input type="text" name="name" ng-model="user.Username" />
<button ng-click="getByUsername(user.Username)">Button</button>
<h4>{{user.Username}}</h4>
<h4>{{user.Name}}</h4>
<h4>{{user.ImageLink}}</h4>
```

Edit:

```
var BlogFeedApp = angular.module('blogFeedApp', ['ngRoute', 'ngResource']).
    config(['$routeProvider', function ($routeProvider) {
        $routeProvider.
            when('/', { controller: MainController, templateUrl: 'posts.html' }).
            when('/test', { controller: MainController, templateUrl: 'test.html' }).
            when('/new-post', { controller: PostController, templateUrl: 'new-post.html' }).
            when('/new-user', { controller: UserController, templateUrl: 'new-user.html' }).
            otherwise({ redirectTo: '/' });
    }]);
```

Comment: We specifically need to see how you are assigning the controller. Is it a custom directive, ng-controller call, etc. Add a plunker or fiddle.

Comment: @btmach I think he supposed to say that he need to see where you have defined `ng-controller`. post your html

Comment: There's no problem with the ng-controller since other methods are working for the same controller on the same template.

Comment: something doesn't make sense here.  your button is taking an `id`, which you are calling from `getByUsername(user.Username)`, but not only does `user.Username` not sound like an `id`, it also looks like the function is receiving a new `user` object to replace the one that was just used to call the function?

Comment: also, your edit to add the Route information is largely pointless, since the routing of the application is not at issue in the question.

Comment: I just noticed that when I added another user it loads all users, it seems to ignore the parameter totally

Comment: well that would make sense, since it's pretty impossible to pass an `id` to the function before you have one.... when the `$http.get` is called, your `id` is `undefined`, and thus your request doesn't pass an `id` to the server, and instead gets all users.  Seems like the problem is with the function you have on your button.

Comment: Any suggestion for an answer?

Comment: it's not really clear here what other HTML is around that snippet you have, which might explain why you are trying to pass a `user.Username` to get a `user` object back... also, that naming convention is pretty unusual.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/82494/discussion-between-claies-and-btmach).

Answer (score 0):

Try removing the `return` keyword on line 2 of your JS.

Comment: Tried it with no success

Answer (score 0):

Use something like following :

```
$scope.getByUsername = function (id) {
    return $http.get('/api/User/' + id).success(function (data) {
        $scope.user = data;
        console.log($scope.user);
        return data;
    });
}
```

This should do the trick.

Answer (score 0):

I think it is because your user is not defined when angularjs bootstrap. Can you try define user outside of $http callback?

```
$scope.user = {};
$scope.user.Username = "";
$scope.getByUsername = function (id) {
return $http.get('/api/User/' + id).success(function (data) {
    $scope.user = data;
    console.log($scope.user);
    return data;
});
```

}